# Able to receive data using $_GET but not $_POST

Tags: php, ajax, post, get

Using Ajax to communicate with server,

I am trying to pass a value to dat.php using AJAX and get another value from dat.php back. The below code works fine when I use GET but doesn't work work with POST. I need to use POST as this is sensitive information I am trying to pass. Any idea hwy this is happening.

This is my code on test.php

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['$PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">

<input type="text" name="value" onchange="ch_email1(this.value)"></input>

</form>



<script>
function ch_email1(str){
    var ajaxRequest;    
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
        try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
        // Something went wrong
                var xl=xmlhttp.responseText
        alert("Something Went wrong");
        return false;
            }
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var xl=ajaxRequest.responseText;
alert (xl);


        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.open("POST","dat.php?q="+str, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}


</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

This is dat.php

```
<?php


$q=$_POST['q'];

echo $q;

?>
```

Please note that above code works fine when I replace POST with GET. Any ides why this is happening.

Comment: If jQuery is an option, I'd recommend using it.  It makes making ajax calls much simpler.

Comment: when you are using post , you can not send the data as querystring.

Comment: Well, you're not sending any *POST data* in the request body...

Comment: Note that POST doesn't protect sensitive data. You may also want to use HTTPS (SSL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help:

```
 ajaxRequest.open("POST","dat.php", true);
 ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 ajaxRequest.send("q="+str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this page.
http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php

Right now, you're sending a post request with nothing in it.  Appending to the url just changes the $_GET variables.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `POST` Ajax call with `GET` way

When you send an AJAX call with POST, you don't have to put parameter on the URL, but you must send parameters using the `.send()` method.

exemple:

```
ajaxRequest.open("POST","dat.php",true);
ajaxRequest.send("q=" + str);
```

You should use a JS librairy like jQuery or other, that will make it for you, instead of re-inventing the wheel and have common problems.